# Cómo puedo hacer que mi id cambie

Tags: javascript

Quiero que mi id sea ejemplo:

Empiece en 1 y ese sea el id, después sea 2 y así conforme se van creando los div en el ciclo for para tomar y así poder mostrar la información depende del id

```
function clicking(posicion){


    var da = (data)

    document.getElementById("SegundoD").innerHTML =" "
        for(var i =0 ; i<da[posicion].Palabras.length ;i++){
        document.getElementById("SegundoD").innerHTML +="<div class='color' onclick='mostrar()' >"+"<h3>"+ da[posicion].Palabras[i].palabra +": </h3>"+"</div>";
    document.getElementById("SegundoD").innerHTML +="<div class='color1' id = 'alo' >"+"<h3>"+ da[posicion].Palabras[i].texto +" </h3>"+"</div>";

    }
}
 function mostrar() {

    document.getElementById('alo').style.display = 'inline-block';

 }
```

Comment: exactamente en dónde quieres poner eso?

Comment: No hagas eso. No necesitas crear ids dinámicamente, en lugar de pasar el índice, pasa el mismo elemento HTML u obtenlo con `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice un pequeño ejemplo donde vas creando divs con ids diferentes dentro de un loop como lo pides:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("crear");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  var wrapperDivs = document.getElementById("divs-wrapper");
  var i = (document.getElementsByClassName("div").length === 0) ? 1 : document.getElementsByClassName("div").length + 1;
  var limite = i + 3;
  
  for(i; i<=limite; i++){
    let div = `<div id="${i}" class="div">Div con el ID ${i}</div>`;
    wrapperDivs.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', div );
  }

});
```

```css
#divs-wrapper{
  padding:5px;
}

.div{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="crear">Crear DIV</button>
<div id="divs-wrapper"></div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: El OP tiene dos divs dentro de su for, creo que le vendría bien cambiar tu ejemplo para asignar ids a dos divs.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el indice i y un prefijo para cada uno de los dos div que creas en cada iteración. Por ejemplo:

```js
function clicking(posicion) {


  var da = (data)

  document.getElementById("SegundoD").innerHTML = " "
  for (var i = 0; i < da[posicion].Palabras.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("SegundoD").innerHTML += "<div class='color' id = 'prefijo-"+i+"' onclick='mostrar()' >" + "<h3>" + da[posicion].Palabras[i].palabra + ": </h3>" + "</div>";
    document.getElementById("SegundoD").innerHTML += "<div class='color1' id = 'alo-"+i+"'>" + "<h3>" + da[posicion].Palabras[i].texto + " </h3>" + "</div>";

  }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que antes al segundo div de cada iteración le estabas poniendo el id "alo". El identificador debería ser único. La función mostrar ya no te valdría.

Comment: muchas gracias.